# NextJS Form Posting Back On Change/Key Press For Inputs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, forms, next.js

I'm working on my first Edit/Update form in a new NextJs app (just learning the framework).  For the life of me, I can't figure out why the form is posting back to the server and the page is refreshing on every keystroke within the input box.  This is a form component being rendered from a main parent page.  What am I missing?

```
    'use client'
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { OrganizationSettings } from "@/services/dataHelper";
import { ManageTeamSettings } from "@/services/teamSettings";

export default async function TeamSettingsFormTemp({ organizationSettings }: { organizationSettings: OrganizationSettings }) {

    const [teamOrganizationName, setTeamOrganizationName] = useState(organizationSettings.organizationAccountSettings?.teamName);
  
    async function updateTeamSettings(formData: FormData) {
        ManageTeamSettings(formData);
    }

    const handleSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      await updateTeamSettings(formData);
    };

    return (
      <>
      <form
        name="teamSettingsForm"
        id="teamSettingsForm"
        className=""
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      >
      <div className="grid grid-cols-12 gap-4 xxxxxl:gap-6">
        <div className="col-span-12 lg:col-span-6">
          <div className="box xxl:p-8 xxxl:p-10">
            <h4 className="h4 bb-dashed mb-4 pb-4 md:mb-6 md:pb-6">
              Account Settings
            </h4>
            <div className="mt-6 xl:mt-8 grid grid-cols-3 gap-4 xxxxxl:gap-6">
              <div className="col-span-2 md:col-span-2">
                <label
                  htmlFor="teamOrganizationName"
                  className="md:text-lg font-medium block mb-4">
                  Team/Organization Name
                </label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="w-full text-sm bg-primary/5 dark:bg-bg3 border border-n30 dark:border-n500 rounded-3xl px-3 md:px-6 py-2 md:py-3"
                  id="teamOrganizationName"
                  name="teamOrganizationName"
                  placeholder="Team Name"
                  value = {teamOrganizationName}
                  required
                  onChange={(e) => {setTeamOrganizationName(e.target.value)}}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="col-span-12 lg:col-span-6">
        </div>
      <div className="col-start-3">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div className="col-start-2 col-end-5">
      <button className="btn flex w-full justify-center" type="submit">
        Save Settings
      </button>
    </div>
    </div>
    </form>
    </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need your component to be async, you should've got the eslint error.

> Error: async/await is not yet supported in Client Components, only Server Components. This error is often caused by accidentally adding `'use client'` to a module that was originally written for the server.

Check https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-async-client-component

I think by removing the async you might have less trouble.